# Correct low pass filter after applying discrete cosine transform

Tags: image-processing, transform, image-compression

I am working on the compression of a bmp image using discrete cosine transform.

First, I split the image into 4x4 blocks and then apply a DCT to each block.

I know that low frequency coefficents (the ones I want to keep for image compression) are grouped in the top left corner.

I want to apply a low pass filter to the DCT matrix, so I only keep the low frequency coefficients. My question is: How do I design the low pass filter? I was thinking, for example of just keeping the 2x2 square from the top left.